# Is there a way to impose memory limit on google or tools pywrapknapsack_solver?

Tags: python, linux, pytorch, knapsack-problem, or-tools

I have created 5,000 instances of a knapsack dataset with each dataset including 100 weights, 100 values, the total weight and a capacity percentage. The weights and values have a normal distribution with mean 100 and std 5. The input file is a pickle formatted as [tensor(weights), tensor(values), tensor(total weight), capacity percentage].
[The pickle input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QH6zr.png)

I have created a python program that takes in the input file, uses the google or tools pywrapknapsack_solver to solve the problem, and outputs the solution as a one-hot vector and the solution time.

```
import torch 
from ortools.algorithms import pywrapknapsack_solver
import time
import pickle
import argparse

def translate_soln(packed_items, num_items):
    out = [0]*num_items
    for i in packed_items:
        out[int(i)] = 1
    return out


def knapsack_solution_generator(input_path, output_path):
    input_data = pickle.load( open(input_path, 'rb'))

    weights = input_data[0].tolist()
    values = input_data[1].tolist()

    total_weight = input_data[2].item()
    capacity_percentage = input_data[3]
    capacity = [total_weight * (capacity_percentage / 100)]

    num_items = len(weights)

    solver = pywrapknapsack_solver.KnapsackSolver(
            pywrapknapsack_solver.KnapsackSolver.
            KNAPSACK_MULTIDIMENSION_BRANCH_AND_BOUND_SOLVER, 'KnapsackExample')
    solver.set_time_limit(7200)
    
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    solver.Init(values, [weights, capacity)
    
    computed_value = solver.Solve()
    end_time = time.perf_counter()

    solution_time = round(end_time - start_time, 5)

    packed_items = []
    for j in range(num_items):
        if solver.BestSolutionContains(j):
            packed_items.append(j)

    solution = translate_soln(packed_items, num_items)
    pickle.dump((solution, solution_time), open(output_path, 'wb'))
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('--input', type=str, help="Input file path")
    parser.add_argument('--output', type=str, help="Output file path")
    
    args = parser.parse_args()
    input_path = args.input
    output_path = args.output

    knapsack_solution_generator(input_path, output_path)
```

I have been using a Linux virtual machine to solve all of these problems independently. However, when the machine attempts to solve problems with capacity percentages of the range 10-90%, there are certain problem instances that will not solve. When looking at the output log, there is a "Killed error". To dig deeper I had the machine attempt to solve the problem instances again as I monitored with the linux top command and saw that the problems that would not solve were killed at 80% memory after about 20 minutes. However, certain problems would be solved in 2 hours. What is causing the solver to use up too much memory? Is there a way to implement a memory constraint?

Comment: Guess: The search-tree is growing too much (which is instance-dependent due to potential *pruning*) because of being [best-first based](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/8d19323faf51f2f004e4de6c1b32a74001fbc7c1/ortools/algorithms/knapsack_solver.cc#L423) (?). The usual approaches in regards to your use-case would be another *budget/resource-limit* like `NodeLimit`. This is [not available though](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/8d19323faf51f2f004e4de6c1b32a74001fbc7c1/ortools/algorithms/knapsack_solver.cc#L394).

Comment: Besides modifying the solver, i would say, that your only chances are: 1) Make more memory available 2) Use more aggressive TimeLimits as *proxy* to not run into memory-limit issues (decrease time available!) 3) More graceful error-handling somehow.

Comment: Hey @sascha, the search-tree growing too much makes logical sense. Somebody reported having the same issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/1046) when using the KNAPSACK_MULTIDIMENSION_BRANCH_AND_BOUND_SOLVER. The solution was to use the KNAPSACK_MULTIDIMENSION_CBC_MIP_SOLVER instead. What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Just try it. Without any special look at the data or practical experience, i would have preferred this one right from the start (as i favor the the theory of the solver). Observing the same problem is not impossible, but i would guess the memory-usage is more stable and (hopefully time-limits are still supported) it's probably easier to guard against this by time-limits (as in the real-world, we might always run into some data where we can't prove the optimum = being incomplete = need to stop early).